# angular checklist-model throws No parent for group element

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to use the [checklist-model](https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model) angular module, but it's raising this error which I can't figure out:

```
No parent form group element found for input element <input type="checkbox" 
  value="correlation" name="question[insights][enable][]"
  id="question_insights_enable_correlation" ng-model="checked"
  class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" bs-validation="">
```

The element is defined by rails:

```
<%= insights_form.check_box("enable", {:multiple => true,
    'checklist-model' => "model.enabled_insights"}, :correlation, nil) %>
```

Which results in:

```
<input checklist-model="model.enabled_insights" type="checkbox" value="correlation"
    name="insights[enable][]" id="insights_enable_correlation" />
```

If I remove the checklist-model attribute, the error goes away. I've googled the error but can't find any reference to anyone else experiencing it.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a problem with the [bootstrap-angular-validation](https://github.com/sagrawal14/bootstrap-angular-validation) library that had been added in another branch of the code.

Wrapping the checkbox element in a `<div class="form-group">` fixed it.